# Is this use of "much" an exception?

Tags: adjectives, usage, adverbs, comparison

The usage of "much" in the following sentence is unclear to me:

> It's not much different.

I learned that "much" cannot qualify the positive degrees of adjectives and adverbs.
So, I wonder if it should be like this:

> It's not much **more** different.

I want to know whether "much" is used correctly in both sentences. Also, if the first one is correct, please tell me when this exception occurs?

Comment: An exception occurs when you try to divide by zero.  Or dereference a null pointer.  You're simply describing an imperfection of a supposed "rule".

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences you give are grammatically correct, and I will describe the details below.  I think perhaps you are not correctly remembering what you learned.  In a general sense, *much* is nearly always used to qualify degree.

- For instance, when *much* is used to modify a noun, *much* describes an uncountable degree:

> We use much with uncountable nouns and many with countable nouns

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers

> Many modifies things that can be counted (i.e., count nouns). Much
>   modifies things that can’t be counted (i.e., mass nouns).

http://grammarist.com/usage/many-much/

- When *much* is used to modify a verb, or otherwise as an adverb, *much* is similarly considered an Adverb of Degree:

> Adverbs of Degree in English help us to show the intensity and the
>   degree in which a specific action is done. These adverbs answer the
>   question: to what degree?

https://lognlearn.jimdo.com/grammar-tips/adverbs/intensifiers-adverbs-of-degree/

- Finally, when *much* is used to modify an adjective, *much* similarly expresses a positive degree of separation:

Where perhaps you became confused is that *much* is an irregular adjective in that while standard adjectives can take their base form to express positive degree, then add *-er* to take a comparative form and *-est* to express superlative degree; *much* is the base form but converts to *more* for comparative form and *most* for superlative form.  You can review from these sites which you will note clearly show that *much* is the positive degree form:

1. [here](https://www.infoplease.com/language-arts/grammar-and-spelling/adjectives-versus-adverbs-three-degrees-separation)
2. [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm)
3. [here](http://www.weblearneng.com/the-degrees-of-comparison)

Also, I note that in the second part of your question, you seem confused about the differences between *much* and *more* (and also *much more* which is the same as *more* except to an unquantifiable greater degree than regular *more*).  Please note these differences between *much* and *more*:

- More is comparative while much does not make any comparison.
- Much can modify an adjective as in much better.
- Much can be used in conjunction with more as in much more experienced or much more talented.
  http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-much-and-vs-more/

So, understanding all the above, you can see that in your first part of your question where you use *much different* that *much* is appropriate and doesn't violate any rules - it shows a positive degree.  In your second part of your question, by using *more different* you are implying that you are making a comparison between at least two things, and whether you say *more different* or *much more different* it still implies that comparison.  The first part of your question (*much different*) doesn't imply any comparison between different things but only a degree of change in the same thing.  So if you mean something like:

> I had visited Washington D.C. ten years ago and returned for a visit
>   last week and my impression is that the city is *not much different*
>   now than it was ten years ago.

then use *much different*, but if you mean something like:

> I had visited both Washington D.C. and Baltimore ten years ago and
>   returned to visit both last week and both had changed, but my
>   impression is that Washington D.C. is *not much more different* than
>   Baltimore, in terms of how much both have changed over the past
>   decade.

then use *much more different*